# LCD does not have Register Select or Read/Write pins. Instead has FLM, LP, CP, and M pins

Tags: lcd, pins, pinout, character-lcd

I have a old Optrex DMF6127N LCD display. I can not find any datasheets for it online (I believe it was made specially for AT&T's Bell Labs) and am trying to get it to work. I have looked at several guides on using LCDs, and they all reference Register Select and Read/Write pins. The LCD that I have, however, is missing those pins, and (supposedly) in their place are the pins FLM, LP, CP, and M.

I have found the datasheets for another LCD from Multi-Inno that can be found [here](https://www.displayfuture.com/Display/datasheet/monographic/MI240160B.pdf). This LCD also has the same pins as my Optrex LCD, and from this I have determined that the pins are as follows:

1. FLM: First Line Marker
2. LP: Data latch signal
3. CP: Clock signal for shifting data
4. M: Alternate signal for LCD drive.

I have spent several hours now searching for how these pins work, but I still have no idea. Does anyone here know how they work? What does each one do? Does anyone have a copy of the datasheet for my LCD? (Optrex DMF6127N)

There are also pins for VSS, VCC, VEE, and pins DU0-3 and DL0-3, which I believe are standard of 8-bit LCD Character displays. (DL0-3 for 4 bit only mode?)

Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, but doubt that the DMF6127N is a "character module" like an HD44780. It is likely a graphics module, where FLM indicates the first line of the display, and pixel data is clocked in for each *line*.

Comment: Optrex DMF6127N may not provide detail, but [NT7701](http://www.pacificdisplay.com/ics_app%20notes/novatek/NT7701Ver2.1.pdf) and [NT7702](https://www.crystalfontz.com/controllers/Novatek/NT7702/395/) do. Those are on the block diagram of [MI24016](https://www.displayfuture.com/Display/datasheet/monographic/MI240160B.pdf), page 5.

Comment: it appears that the display is an LCD monitor ... it requires a video signal at the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LCD you have does not have a character interface of a HD44780 controller - the point of 8-bit character displays is that provides you an 8-bit ASCII compatible interface that can be connected to a bus, and internally the controller knows how to constantly drive the rows and columns of the display with pixel data, and that's the kind of interface your display has - a direct interface for driving 4-bit pixel data directly to rows and columns, so you have to scan the display yourself.

Here's a link to similar controller : [DMF-682AN](https://datasheet.octopart.com/DMF-682AN-EW-Optrex-datasheet-24516.pdf)